# Proving a general formula for "tangent vectors" (actually $k$-th partial derivatives) when changing coordinates

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, jet-bundles

I want to prove that the order of contact of two functions $f, g: M \to N$ between manifolds is well defined.

> **Definition.** Let $f, g : M^{n} \to N^{m}$ be smooth functions. We say $f$ has order of contact $k$ at $p \in M$ with $g$, and write $f \sim_{k} g$ at $p \in M$ if there exist charts $\varphi: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\psi: V \to \mathbb{R}^m$ around $p \in M$ and $f(p) \in N$ such that $f(p) = g(p)$ and all the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ in the charts up to order $k$ coincide at $p$, that is:
>
> $$\frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial r^{\alpha}}(r^j \circ \psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1})(\varphi(p)) = \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial r^{\alpha}}(r^j \circ \psi \circ g \circ \varphi^{-1})(\varphi(p))$$
>
> for every multi-index $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n)$ (where $|\alpha| = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n$) and every $1 \leq j \leq m$, where we define:
>
> $$\frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial r^{\alpha}} \doteq \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial r^{\alpha_1} \cdots \partial r^{\alpha_n}}$$
>
> and $r^j: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ is the projection onto the $j$-th coordinate and $\frac{\partial}{\partial r^{k}}$ is just the ordinary (Euclidean) $k$-th partial derivative.

I'm trying to prove this definition does not depend on charts, that is, if the above is satisfied in charts $\varphi = (x^1, \cdots, x^n), \psi = (y^1, \cdots, y^m)$, then it's also satisfied in any other charts $\tilde{\varphi} = (\tilde{x}^1, \cdots, \tilde{x}^n), \tilde{\psi} = (\tilde{y}^1, \cdots, \tilde{y}^m)$. I've been able to prove it is well defined if $k = 1$ or $k = 2$ by using the chain rule in the form of the following formulas (where I'm using Einstein notation):

> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} = \frac{\partial x^{\ell}}{\partial y^i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\ell}}$$
>
> $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^{i} \partial y^j} = \frac{\partial^2 x^{\ell}}{\partial y^i \partial y^j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\ell}} + \frac{\partial x^{\ell}}{\partial y^j} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial y^i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$

and I think the general case has to be done by induction, but I'm having trouble actually using the inductive hypothesis, since I'd have to obtain a relation between the $k$-th partial derivatives in relation to different charts (which in turn I'd also have to use induction to obtatin, but I'm failing to see the pattern in order to think of the formula I'd want to prove for this general case). I'd really appreciate some help on this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really necessary to write down an explicit formula. Instead one can note that every term in the expression for $\frac{\partial^p f^j}{\partial y^{i_1}\cdots\partial y^{i_p}}$ is of the form
$$
a\frac{\partial^q f^j}{\partial x^{k_1}\cdots\partial x^{k_q}}
$$
where $a\in C^\infty M$ does not depend on $f$ and $q\le p$. Taking another partial derivative (w.r.t. $x$ or $y$)of such a term will produce more terms of the same form, and the order of the partial derivatives of $f$ will increase by at most $1$.

Comment: I think I get it now. Just one last thing: so it was only really ever necessary to prove it's well defined for $k = 1$, right? Thank you!

Comment: Once you've proven the $k=1$ case, you can use strong induction on $k$ by showing that if every partial derivative of order $p\le k$ can be written as a sum of terms in the above form, then every partial derivative of order $p=k+1$ can also be written this way.

Comment: I see. But then how can we argue that the sum of all of these terms will in the end be a single $(k+1)$-th partial derivative in respect to the new chart? I mean, I'd argue that since we started with a single one then you can just go backwards, but is there more to it than that?

Comment: It won't be a single partial derivative in general. A partial derivative in the new chart will be equal to a $C^\infty M$-linear combination of partial derivatives in the old chart.